# How to enable vscode editor.hover only for specific lanauge?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't want to enable all the times, it's sometimes annoying.

Comment: it may be more useful to add a button to the IDE

Comment: you can set the hover delay to a large value, you can customize settings for a language, so set the hover delay to large values for the languages that annoy you, I have set it for html because all the hints for known tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First disable the hover for all languages and then enable it for specific languages, in your `settings.json` like this:

```
  "editor.hover.enabled": false,

  "[scss]": {
    "editor.hover.enabled": true
  }
```

You can put multiple languages in the specific setting like:

```
  "[scss, css]": {
    "editor.hover.enabled": true
  }
```